# Cannot access item in an object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access item in an object but it return null. What is wrong with this code.

my object in console log

```
[Object {name="Name 1"}, Object {name="name 2"}]

const itemname = obj;
console.log(itemname.name); // it return null
```

Comment: Can you show what ```obj``` is?

Comment: [Object {name="Name 1"}, Object {name="name 2"}] this is the value of obj in console log. I'm trying to get a name in that object.

Comment: in that case, ```obj``` is an ```Array```. It is not ```Object```.

Comment: Ok sorry for that. Even I use JSON.stringify(obj). It will return also the itemname.name to null.

Comment: Why do you want to use ```JSON.stringify(obj)```? It will give you ```String``` not an ```Object```

Comment: You have an ```Array```. So you only need to get the object you want in that array. For example ```obj[0].name```

Comment: obj[0].name this one work me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a array of objects. so you need to specify the index of witch element you want.
example `console.log(itemname[0].name);`